# Android google cloud messaging

Tags: android, google-api-php-client

i try to send message from my server to google cloud server, but  i have problem with it...
i get server key(Key for server applications), set it to this code:

```
 $headers = array(
    'Authorization: key=' .My server key,
    'Content-Type: application/json'
);
$ch = curl_init();
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $url);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, true);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, $headers);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
curl_setopt ($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYHOST, 0);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, false);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, json_encode($fields));
$result = curl_exec($ch);
```

after sending message i have such result:

Unauthorized
Error 401

I use such ip:78.47.150.20

but when i use test ip 0.0.0.0/0 i haven't any problems....

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
function sendNotification($registrationIdsArray, $messageData) {
  $apiKey = "YOUR_API_KEY";

 $headers = array("Content-Type:" . "application/json", "Authorization:" . "key=" .   $apiKey);
 $data = array(
 'data' => $messageData,
 'registration_ids' => $registrationIdsArray
 );

$ch = curl_init();

  curl_setopt( $ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, $headers );
curl_setopt( $ch, CURLOPT_URL, "https://android.googleapis.com/gcm/send" );
curl_setopt( $ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYHOST, 0 );
curl_setopt( $ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, 0 );
curl_setopt( $ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true );
curl_setopt( $ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, json_encode($data) );

$response = curl_exec($ch);
curl_close($ch);

return $response;
}
```

Comment: the abovfe link gives me  {"multicast_id":8142008928614681488,"success":1,"failure":0,"canonical_ids":0,"results":[{"message_id":"0:1411015000919118%5d450aecf9fd7ecd"}]} . check again.