# FCM Field "data" must be a JSON array

Tags: arrays, json, firebase

Hi im working with postman to make my json object FCM message:
But when i try to send:

```
    {  
   "to":"fzvihT7dFUI:APA91bFVhnWAxXVjlWiiHIs9ZUyL1DE2hZO6GpItJtReh3hcKF1kD6mLuQq9fNP9xvS5bOFWUOG-OW-uyOedc1C43m8jfvD4OOfsBYuMbM7t1-dZEy2kQcuv3gJw6dhneVus2AR_hQHQ",
   "data":[  
      {  
         "time":1501385514224,
         "CC":"1030626890"
      }
   ],
   "notification":{  
      "body":"SPO2:95 \nPulso:75",
      "title":"El paciente Daniel Ortiz nesecita asistencia"
   }
}
```

The response its:

> Field "data" must be a JSON array:
>   [{"CC":"1030626890","time":1501385514224}]

But i know the `[{"CC":"1030626890","time":1501385514224}]` its a array, i dont understand the problem.
What i made wrong?

Comment: Adding to the answer, the payload most always be String, so I'm not sure you can have an array

Answer (score 8, accepted):

From the [Firebase Cloud Messaging documentation](https://firebase.google.com/docs/cloud-messaging/concept-options#data_messages), it seems like `data` should be a JSON object:

```
{
   "to" : "bk3RNwTe3H0:CI2k_HHwgIpoDKCIZvvDMExUdFQ3P1...",
   "data" : {
     "Nick" : "Mario",
     "body" : "great match!",
     "Room" : "PortugalVSDenmark"
   },
 }
```

I'm not sure why the error message talks says it needs to be an array. It's like meant as an [*"associative array"*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Associative_array) which is really just another term for a JSON object.

Answer (score 2):

I might be too late but for those who still face this problem , following change saved me.

By adding `JSON_FORCE_OBJECT` to `json_encode()` it will add missing braces so it should be something like this:

```
json_encode($fields ,JSON_FORCE_OBJECT));
```

That's it.

Answer (score 0):

In case you serialize sql/api results data that each item of the array has a numeric key using php, for example an array like:

```
$results = [
   ['name'=>'john', 'durname'=>'doe'],
   ['chuck'=>'john', 'durname'=>'Norris'],
]
```

Before turning into FCM data try:

```
$results = [
   ["time":1501385514224, "CC":"1030626890"]
   ["time":1501385514334, "CC":"1030126890"]
]

$fcmData = [  
   "to"=>"fzvihT7dFUI:APA91bFVhnWAxXVjlWiiHIs9ZUyL1DE2hZO6GpItJtReh3hcKF1kD6mLuQq9fNP9xvS5bOFWUOG-OW-uyOedc1C43m8jfvD4OOfsBYuMbM7t1-dZEy2kQcuv3gJw6dhneVus2AR_hQHQ",
   "data":[  
     "data" => $results
   ],
   "notification" => [  
      "body"=>"SPO2:95 \nPulso:75",
      "title"=>"El paciente Daniel Ortiz nesecita asistencia"
   ]
]

$fcmData = json_encode($fcmData);

// Send push notification here
```

In case you are using laravel with `brozot/laravel-fcm`, a good approach is this [one](https://stackoverflow.com/a/69190687/4706711).

Thje bottom line is that fcm/push notification data *MUST* be an *associative array*.