# How I can serialize database results as FCM/Push notification data?

Tags: php, firebase, firebase-cloud-messaging, laravel-5.8

I made a controller that sends push notification some data fetched from database:

```
use App\Model\MyModel;

use LaravelFCM\Message\PayloadDataBuilder;
use LaravelFCM\Message\PayloadNotificationBuilder;
use LaravelFCM\Facades\FCM;

//come code here

$data = MyModel::where('foreignh_table_id',id)->select('col1','col2','col3')->get()->toArray();

$dataBuilder = new PayloadDataBuilder();
$dataBuilder->addData($data);

$fcmTopic = new Topics();
$fcmTopic->topic('lorem_ipsum');


 $title = __('pn_title',['client' => 'JohnDOE']);
 $notificationBuilder = new PayloadNotificationBuilder($title);
 $notification = $notificationBuilder->build();

 $status = FCM::sendToTopic($topic,null,$notification,$data);
```

But On line:

```
 $status = FCM::sendToTopic($topic,null,$notification,$data);
```

I get the following error:

```
"Field \"data\" must be a JSON array:
```

Based on this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/45396133/4706711) each push notification mush be an associative array and not an array of items.

So how I can send the database results back to an android app via FCM?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Data send back must be an associative array meaning that each item of the data must have a non-numeric key. A quick solution is to set the result to an associative array like this:

```
use App\Model\MyModel;

use LaravelFCM\Message\PayloadDataBuilder;
use LaravelFCM\Message\PayloadNotificationBuilder;
use LaravelFCM\Facades\FCM;

//come code here

$data = MyModel::where('foreignh_table_id',id)->select('col1','col2','col3')->get()->toArray();

$dataBuilder = new PayloadDataBuilder();
$dataBuilder->addData([ 'data' => $data ]);

$fcmTopic = new Topics();
$fcmTopic->topic('lorem_ipsum');


 $title = __('pn_title',['client' => 'JohnDOE']);
 $notificationBuilder = new PayloadNotificationBuilder($title);
 $notification = $notificationBuilder->build();

 $status = FCM::sendToTopic($topic,null,$notification,$data);
```

Pay attention on the line:

```
$dataBuilder->addData([ 'data' => $data ]);
```

What I do is that I set a key for the provided data, therefore once serialized it will turn into an object/associative array.

Therefore as a result any data provided in `PayloadDataBuilder::addData` must be an associative array.

An another approach could be to turn any numeric key into a string. Though, I have not tested and I have no code to offer.